# Why is the centre point of the United Kingdom in Scotland on the Developer Survey Results

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2016

I was just browsing through the [developer survey results](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016) and noticed that the centre blog for the United Kingdom is in Scotland.

[image]

How is this calculated? I can't imagine that this is the mean location for all survey respondents from the UK as the top part of scotland is very sparsely populated.

I would have thought that the blob location should be one of the following:

- [London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London) (the capital of the United Kingdom)
- One of the [Centre points of the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centre_points_of_the_United_Kingdom#Traditional_locations)
- The mean location of respondents
- Centre of population

I am interested to know if this is a bug or there is some reason for this?

Comment: I blame brexit.

Comment: Other countries (most notably Germany) are suffering from this, too.

Comment: For Germany, the dot seems to line up with Bremen but that could just be a coincidence since Scotland's isn't close to any city.

Comment: In the case of germany this *could* be the mean location of all respondents I suppose

Comment: @Glorfindel "suffering" seems a bit strong haha

Comment: Where does it state it's _supposed_ to be the centre? Maybe someone just wanted to reap havoc on all the intrinsic OCD impulses that we have on SO

Comment: @MacroMan - it doesn't state that but I find it strange that some are slap band in the centre and others are right on the coast/border

Comment: For Czech Republic the dot position is also strange.

Comment: And that's not where Paris is either; looks more like Tours.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check the source code of that page. It's a standard Highcharts World map (see http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/map-collection) – so nothing to blame on SO.

It's not a bug, it's a feature (because it says so in the data):

```
{"type":"Feature","id":"GB","properties":
    {"hc-group":"admin0",
     "hc-middle-x":0.59,
     "hc-middle-y":0.01,
     ...
```

where `hc-middle-x` and `hc-middle-y` are "[d]efined as fraction of map bounding box width".

Given the largely vertical orientation of the UK's main body of land, a value `0.01` is indeed peculiar, and one would expect something more near to `0.5`.

You can report your issues with Highcharts via [their website](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/repo-guidelines.md#reporting-issues).

Comment: Ah, a standards Highlands World map. We could have known.

Comment: @MrLister: well maybe not. [A recent version](http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/map-bubble) shows bubbles centered onto nation's capitals.

Comment: .. uh at least for the UK (which was what the question was about). The entire rest of the world seems messed up (Paris isn't that low, the captial of the USA is not in Colorado, and despite the number of visitors, the capital of The Netherlands is not on Texel).